# merging large data.frame to fill missing hourly dates

Tags: r, join, merge

I want to fill some missing dates in large data.frames. I saw different posts, but nothing is working. I'm using merge, which I thought it would be easy, but the result is not what I expect.

My data consists on hourly data for the whole year, with the corresponding values of a variable. I show just a sample:

```
# sample of data
dput(head(x1))
structure(list(date = structure(c(14617, 14617, 14617, 14617, 
  14617, 14617), class = "Date"), value = c(-9999, -9999, -9999, 
  -9999, -9999, -9999)), .Names = c("date", "value"), row.names = 
  c(2923L, 6545L, 10167L, 13789L, 17411L, 21033L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, since I want to add the missing data I created the array with the correct and complete time series:

```
# Create hourly data

times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 23:00:00"), by="hour")
# Split into days and hours
nt <- as.Date(strptime(times, "%Y-%m-%d"))
ndays <- data.frame("date"=nt,"hour"=format(as.POSIXct(strptime(times,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

The, I tried to merge `ndays` and `x1`, to have a new `data.frame` with the whole dates (and hours):

```
newdata <- merge(ndays,x1,by="date",all.x  = T)
```

But, I don't have the values of `x1`! I'd have `NA`,  so I tried to combine different options of merge, but none it's working. If I use:

```
newdata <- merge(x1, ndays,by="date",all.x = T)
```

The result looks like:

```
head(newdata)
  date       value hour
1 2010-01-08 -9999 12:00:00
2 2010-01-08 -9999 01:00:00
3 2010-01-08 -9999 02:00:00
4 2010-01-08 -9999 03:00:00
5 2010-01-08 -9999 00:00:00
6 2010-01-08 -9999 05:00:00
.....
```

But what I want is:

```
head(newdata)
date       value   hour
2010-01-01 NA      00:00:00    
........
2010-01-08 -9999   12:00:00
2010-01-08 -9999   01:00:00
2010-01-08 -9999   02:00:00
```

To have the whole dates, and the final expected data.frame has to have a length (for each column) 8760 = the number of hours per year (timestep).
If I do:

```
newdata <- merge(ndays,x1,by="date",all = T)
```

Again, I'd have a new data.frame with a length of 193680, because all the data is merged. But I only want the values of x1 and days and hours for the whole year.

What am I missing to work with merge? Should I write another function to do it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want but as `x1` is the target data frame you should put it first in `merge` function: `newdata <- merge(x1, ndays,by="date",all.x  = T)`

Comment: as expected newdata has non NAs for variable 'value' only for dates that exist in x1. Could you provide a sample of your expected result?

Comment: I just edited the question in order to explain better what I wanted to do.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do exactly - your question's layout is a little messed up. Do you want this: `merge(x1, newdata, by = "date", all.x = T, all.y = F)` ?!?

Comment: I think I get it now: You want for each day of the year all hours and the values from x1 if there is any. If not, you want an NA. Then, this should do it: `merge(x1, newdata, by = "date", all.x = T, all.y = T)`

Comment: I want for each day of the year all hours with the values from x1 if there are, or NA if there aren't, as you say. I tried it again following your suggestion and it's not working. Besides I get a final data.frame with more than 8760..(timespets or day-hours, repeated..) ..so I am not sure how to use merge here.

Comment: In your `x1`, is there a column with the hour missing? Wouldn't you need the hour of the value? At the moment, there are only repeated values for 2010-01-08. Without the hour information, you do not know which hour the specific value is for, do you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I believe this can be solved by *updating in a join*. This is a special kind of left join, i.e., take all rows of `nday` and copy `value` only in those rows where a matching `date` is found:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ndays)[unique(setDT(x1)), on = "date", value := value]
```

Note that only unique rows of `x1` are used assuming that there is only one distinct value per day.

```
# show some relevant rows
ndays[date %in% (as.IDate("2010-01-08") + (-1:+1))]
```

> ```
>           date     hour value
>  1: 2010-01-07 00:00:00    NA
>  2: 2010-01-07 01:00:00    NA
>  3: 2010-01-07 02:00:00    NA
>  4: 2010-01-07 03:00:00    NA
>  5: 2010-01-07 04:00:00    NA
>  6: 2010-01-07 05:00:00    NA
>  7: 2010-01-07 06:00:00    NA
>  8: 2010-01-07 07:00:00    NA
>  9: 2010-01-07 08:00:00    NA
> 10: 2010-01-07 09:00:00    NA
> 11: 2010-01-07 10:00:00    NA
> 12: 2010-01-07 11:00:00    NA
> 13: 2010-01-07 12:00:00    NA
> 14: 2010-01-07 13:00:00    NA
> 15: 2010-01-07 14:00:00    NA
> 16: 2010-01-07 15:00:00    NA
> 17: 2010-01-07 16:00:00    NA
> 18: 2010-01-07 17:00:00    NA
> 19: 2010-01-07 18:00:00    NA
> 20: 2010-01-07 19:00:00    NA
> 21: 2010-01-07 20:00:00    NA
> 22: 2010-01-07 21:00:00    NA
> 23: 2010-01-07 22:00:00    NA
> 24: 2010-01-07 23:00:00    NA
> 25: 2010-01-08 00:00:00 -9999
> 26: 2010-01-08 01:00:00 -9999
> 27: 2010-01-08 02:00:00 -9999
> 28: 2010-01-08 03:00:00 -9999
> 29: 2010-01-08 04:00:00 -9999
> 30: 2010-01-08 05:00:00 -9999
> 31: 2010-01-08 06:00:00 -9999
> 32: 2010-01-08 07:00:00 -9999
> 33: 2010-01-08 08:00:00 -9999
> 34: 2010-01-08 09:00:00 -9999
> 35: 2010-01-08 10:00:00 -9999
> 36: 2010-01-08 11:00:00 -9999
> 37: 2010-01-08 12:00:00 -9999
> 38: 2010-01-08 13:00:00 -9999
> 39: 2010-01-08 14:00:00 -9999
> 40: 2010-01-08 15:00:00 -9999
> 41: 2010-01-08 16:00:00 -9999
> 42: 2010-01-08 17:00:00 -9999
> 43: 2010-01-08 18:00:00 -9999
> 44: 2010-01-08 19:00:00 -9999
> 45: 2010-01-08 20:00:00 -9999
> 46: 2010-01-08 21:00:00 -9999
> 47: 2010-01-08 22:00:00 -9999
> 48: 2010-01-08 23:00:00 -9999
> 49: 2010-01-09 00:00:00    NA
> 50: 2010-01-09 01:00:00    NA
> 51: 2010-01-09 02:00:00    NA
> 52: 2010-01-09 03:00:00    NA
> 53: 2010-01-09 04:00:00    NA
> 54: 2010-01-09 05:00:00    NA
> 55: 2010-01-09 06:00:00    NA
> 56: 2010-01-09 07:00:00    NA
> 57: 2010-01-09 08:00:00    NA
> 58: 2010-01-09 09:00:00    NA
> 59: 2010-01-09 10:00:00    NA
> 60: 2010-01-09 11:00:00    NA
> 61: 2010-01-09 12:00:00    NA
> 62: 2010-01-09 13:00:00    NA
> 63: 2010-01-09 14:00:00    NA
> 64: 2010-01-09 15:00:00    NA
> 65: 2010-01-09 16:00:00    NA
> 66: 2010-01-09 17:00:00    NA
> 67: 2010-01-09 18:00:00    NA
> 68: 2010-01-09 19:00:00    NA
> 69: 2010-01-09 20:00:00    NA
> 70: 2010-01-09 21:00:00    NA
> 71: 2010-01-09 22:00:00    NA
> 72: 2010-01-09 23:00:00    NA
>           date     hour value
> ```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it's not working for me..I got values that do not correspond to the original array x1 :( .. however, I tried another way (creating my own function) and doing something like,   # create empty column values ndays$value <- NA # find common dates  ind  <- which(ndays$date %in% mydata$date) # fill the values where there is a date    ndays$value[ind] <-mydata$value ...

Comment: Does `x1` contain more than one distinct value per day?

Comment: BTW: have you tried `merge(x1, ndays, by = "date", all.y = TRUE)`? Note the `all.y`.

Comment: Aha, ok, that's why it wasn't working then..I checked it and I have same values in one days (some hours seem to have the same values), so I guess that it's the reason, am I right? ..and yes, I tried several combinations with merge, but none worked in my case...Thanks!

Comment: If there are two values per date then merge/join duplicates the rows.